# Is there a difference between $a \cdot a^T$ and $a^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, taylor-expansion

The title says it all... I can't see the difference between $a \cdot a^T$ and $a^2$, when $a$ is a vector. However I encountered a formula stating 
$$\frac{1}{|y+a|} = \frac{1}{|y|} - \frac{y \cdot a }{|y|^3} +  \frac{1}{2}  \frac{y^T \cdot (3\cdot a \cdot a^T - |a|^2) \cdot y}{|y|^5} + \cdots$$
where $a$ and $y$ are again vectors (Taylor-expansion).

Why is the term in the brackets not simply $ 2 \cdot a^2$?

Comment: I've never seen $a^2$ mean anything when $a$ is a vector... nor $1/y$ for that matter. Where did you encounter this formula?

Comment: I found it in a Skript. I editied it now. I think this is what was meant.

Comment: @Rahul It does have a meaning in geometric algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it now. The term in the brackets is to be interpreted as a matrix $M$ like

$$M_{ij} = 3 a_i a_j - \delta_{ij} |a|^2$$

This makes a lot more sense. But I am not quite sure how to distinguish that from the ordinary dot product...